# Multiway merge on keys with duplicates not working

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to do a multi-way left join that doesn't seem to work.

```
# Create dummy dataframes
lt = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K3', 'K4', 'K5'],
                    'A': ['A0', 'AX', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']})

other = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K8'],
                       'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', '32']})        

other2 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K10'],
                       'C': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', '99']}) 

# Create list of dataframes
dfs=[lt,other,other2]

# Set index to 'key' column for all list elements
dfs = [df.set_index('key') for df in dfs]

# Perform the multi-way left join
final = dfs[0].join(dfs[1:],  how = 'left').reset_index()
```

Returns [final]:

```
    key A   B   C
0   K0  A0  B0  B0
1   K0  AX  B0  B0
2   K1  A1  B1  B1
3   K10         99
4   K2  A2  B2  B2
5   K3  A3      
6   K4  A4      
7   K5  A5      
8   K8      32
```

Whereas, I need the result [final] as:

```
    key A   B   C
0   K0  A0  B0  B0
1   K0  AX  B0  B0
2   K1  A1  B1  B1
3   K2  A2  B2  B2
4   K3  A3      
5   K4  A4      
6   K5  A5
```

What am I doing wrong ? I tried doing this between only two dataframes [lt] and [other] and that doesn't work either. I am thinking it' something to do with the list creation step. Any insight would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Your approach should be working fine.  I get your desired output

Comment: your commands work fine. I suspect you specified `how='outer'` instead of `'left'`, so the `key` column gets all combined values. Make sure specify `how='left'`

Comment: I don't get the same result. Are we on different versions ? i ma running Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40)